# How to add a background image into a div column

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've created two unequal columns that float next to each other. The smaller column on the right i'm happy with however i want to add a background image to the one on the left but it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried using the same code as the column on the right and doing style=background-image:... but that didn't work. It only worked if i did background color.

```
    .column left {
background-image: url('i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg');
background-size: cover;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="row">
<div class="column left" >

  </div>
  <div class="column right" style="background-color:#FDE4EC;">
```

I would like the image to fill the background of the column on the left but right now it shows blank.

Thank you

Comment: `.column left` should be `.column.left` to start with. Also the div has no size at present.

Comment: @Paulie_D - good spot, I hope you don't mind me stealing it and putting a more detailed description in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `url(...)` should be a full URL... otherwise you're trying to load a file that is local to your domain.

So update...

```
background-image: url('i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg');
```

To...

```
background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg');
```

(Or `https://` if that is more appropriate)

```css
.column {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:100vh;
}
.left {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
.right {
  background-color:#FDE4EC;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column right"></div>
</div>
```

---

Also, as noticed by @Paulie_D in their comment to your original post, your CSS selector needs to be `.column.left` instead of `.column left`.

In your element `class="column left"` means that it uses both classes `column` and `left`.

But in your CSS if you put `.column left` selector it means you'll only format elements called `<left>` which are contained within elements that have `class="column"`.

By using `.column.left` you're formatting elements which have **both** classes

Comment: Thank you so much, may i ask how to center it correctly within the column?

Comment: See edited snippet code (use [`image-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position))

Comment: oh sorry i'm new here i didn't realise

Comment: Don't apologise... I edited my answer to include the `image-position` CSS instruction in the snippet.  Expand it by clicking "Show code snippet" and then you can run it to see it in action

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you. Your Url was not declared properly. moreover you have use bootstrap and into the row class you need to add a class to divided the screen into left and right. I have tried to make your code structure little bit better. please have a look.

```css
.col-sm-6.column.left {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 column left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 column right" style="background-color:#FDE4EC;">
    right
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you've done to fix the OP's issue, rather than just giving code and expecting people to work out what the difference is

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="column left">
  </div>
  <div class="column right" style="background-color:#FDE4EC;">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column.left {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/k5gf0zz.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.column.right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;

}
```

Issues with your code:

1. Incorrect `URL`
2. No giving width, height and position to the `div` block

[codepen working demo](https://codepen.io/nitinnairdev/pen/RzMVoz)

Comment: Why are you using codepen when SO provides [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: @freefaller Apologies as I am new to SO, and I have a habit of using codepen. Will try next time. Thanks for the info btw.